# Make custom page with edit form accessible for use as default edit form

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath, list-form

I've created a custom page with 3 web zones in a site pages library. One zone is an infopath edit form for list A. Is it possible to get that custom page to show up on the list of available forms to choose from as the default edit form in SharePoint designer for list A?

I've tried importing the custom page into various folders in the site hierarchy but its not showing up as a viable option. Is it even possible? If so, how?

Alternately I can't get a custom form to display various web part zone options if I use the standard SPD way of creating custom forms where it does allow me to choose it.